# random choice is always return 1 as answer(simple game)

Tags: python, random

ok, I'm new to python(or coding in general) and I was trying to make a simple guessing game, the program decides on a number from 1 to 5 and the player tries to guess it, but every time I answer 1 it says correct, even when it is another number when you print. another problem I've been having is that the loop only lasts a short time, is that supposed to happen?

```
        import random
            num_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,]
            num = random.choice(num_list)
            ur_num = input("pick a number, 1 to 5")

            for num in num_list:
                if int(ur_num) != num:
                    print("try again")
                    ur_num = input("pick a number, 1 to 5")
                else:
                    print("GOOD JOB")
                    again = input("wanna play again?(y/n)")
                    if again == "y":
                        num = random.choice(num_list)
                        print("OKIE DOKIE")
                    else:
                        print("Have a nice day!")
                        break
```

Comment: You're using `num` for the random choice and the loop variable

Comment: With "for num..." you overwrite the previous value of "num". Generally a for-loop doesn't make sense here.

Comment: Just convert the for loop to a while True: and it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are redefining the `num` variable in your for loop.

When your code comes to the

```
for num in num_list:
```

It will reassign `num` to `1` in the first iteration, then `2` then `3` ect..

So the input will be checking against `1`, the second input will be checking against `2` and so on through the array.

Comment: thanks so much, I've been stuck on this for a while and couldn't figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

The use of a while loop instead of a for loop will fix both of your problems.

Right now, in your for loop, `num` cycles through the `num_list` array which overides the use of the "num" from the previous one you set, assigned to a random number.

Also, your loop isn't lasting a long time because `for num in num_list` will just cylce through the values in `num_list`, each time assigning to the num object.

A while loop will continually repeat itself until a break statement is called.

```
     while(true): #continually cycles through until a break is called
            ur_num = input("pick a number, 1 to 5")
            if int(ur_num) != num:
                print("try again")
                continue #goes to next iteration of while loop
            else:
                print("GOOD JOB")
                again = input("wanna play again?(y/n)")
                if again == "y":
                    num = random.choice(num_list)
                    print("OKIE DOKIE")
                    continue
                else:
                    print("Have a nice day!")
                    break #exits loop
```